# passing dynamic value to config

Tags: php, laravel

I want to set a dynamic value in my config(laravel framework).

I want to set default currency that a user used to logout .ie when a user logout with a currency code then whenever that user login that currency should shown as default, here i created a custom provider in app.php
/*config*/
       App\Providers\DefaultCurrencyProvider::class,
in DefaultCurrencyProvider i created ,

```
public function boot()
       {
            view()->composer(['app.user*'],function($view){
            $user_currency = User::where('id',Auth::id())>value('user_currency');            
           $user_currency);
           Config::set('currency.default',$user_currency);
       });
    }
```

i want to set user_currency as default

Comment: What is your question? What errors/issues are you facing?

Comment: Seeing you already store it in the user model, I would load it to the session when a user logs in (or is logged in, but the default currency is not set in the session yet). The config is more for runtime stuff and configuration of your whole application.